# Button click not moving to the new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

On pressing the send button in my code, it must move to the new activity which i created. But this is not taking place. I have the code below. 
Please help. I am just a beginner in android studio.

.xml file(layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="@string/button_send" />
```

main activity

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String message=editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);

}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>


    </activity>


</application>
```

Please help in resolving the issue. I am new to Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correct code, only thing you are missing is to call the startActivity call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
String message=editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
startActivity(intent);
```

You forgot to call this...

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget to call

```
startActivity(intent);
```

full code should be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
String message=editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
startActivity(intent);
```

here is the Official  [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: @Nithin cp welcome to Stack overflow...if the answer helps mark it as correct by clicking tick sign next to answer

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my part.
I didnt write the statement to invoke the intent.

```
startActivity(intent);
```

I know this was just silly on my part. But these mistakes can happen to anyone,  I hope this helps other people.

Full Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
String message=editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
startActivity(intent);
```